# Not getting the closest to 0 result

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am not able to find the closest number to 0
its providing me the wrong result.
Can you tell me how to fix it?
Instead of index how to get the value as result -0.001.
Providing fiddle and code below:

http://jsfiddle.net/YYg8U/7/

```
var myNumbersToSort = [-1, 2, -3, 4, 0.3,1,-0.001];
function getClosestToZero(set) {
  if(0 === set.length) return null;
  var closest = Math.abs(set[0]), result = 0;
  for(var i in set) {
     var next = Math.abs(set[i]);
     if(closest > next) {
       result = i;
       closest = next;
     }
  }
  return result;  
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (getClosestToZero(myNumbersToSort));
```

Answer (score 1):

Good news!

It works. the only thing you missed that your function returns the index Since -0.001 is the closest to 0 it gives six, (array starts from index 0)

I simply tried it with closest as the return value and it worked, try it with different numbers and you will see.

with 
var myNumbersToSort = [-1, 2,0.000001, -3, 4, 0.3,1,-0.001]

it gives **2** since the second element is 0.000001

Comment: thanks for your reply instead of index how to get the value as result -0.001

Comment: 'return closest' instead of 'return result' because variable result corresponds to the index